# Django: Load form with dynamic fields

Tags: python, django, forms

I created a form with multiple dynamic fields (no class attributes) which are added to `self.fields` in the `__init__` function like this:

```
class CustomForm(django.forms.Form):
    def __init__(dynamic_fields, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for name, field in dynamic_fields.items():
            self.fields[name] = field

dynamic_fields = {'val1': IntegerField(), 'val2': FloatField()}
CustomForm(dynamic_fields)
```

Now, I don't know how to load the Form after a `POST` request. Normally, I would do something like:

```
custom_form = CustomForm(request.POST)
if custom_form.is_valid():
    data = custom_form.cleaned_data
    ...
```

But as the fields are not known to Form when `super` is called, I don't know how to load fields manually afterwards. Ideas?

Comment: are field keys always point to the same field type?

Comment: no, field types can be of every valid django field type

Answer (score 1):

You could update `base_fields` before calling the `super` `__init__`:

```
class CustomForm(django.forms.Form):
    def __init__(dynamic_fields, *args, **kwargs):
        self.base_fields.update(dynamic_fields)
        super(CustomForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

dynamic_fields = {'val1': IntegerField(), 'val2': FloatField()}
CustomForm(dynamic_fields)
```

Comment: This did the trick! After calling `custom = CustomForm(dynamic_fields, request.POST)` I can continue calling `custom.is_valid()` and get data via `custum.cleaned_data`. Thanks!

Comment: Just found out that your solution does not work if you use multiple `CustomForms` on one page. This is, because `base_fields` is class attribute. Thus, changing it changes fields for **all** `CustomForms`, leading to field copies in every form.

Comment: Certainly the solution is quite hacky. But I think that's in the nature of what you're trying to do. In the `__init__´ of `BaseForm` the `fields` attribute is created by copying `self.base_fields`.
So I guess making a copy of `self.base_fields` in `CustomForm`s `init` before the `update` call and resetting it after calling `super`s `init` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked to just set data attribute from `Form` class, similar to `__init__` function of the `Form` class. Also, the `is_bound` attribute has to be set to validate form via `is_valid()` method:

```
class CustomForm(django.forms.Form):
    def __init__(dynamic_fields, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for name, field in dynamic_fields.items():
            self.fields[name] = field
        self.is_bound = data is not None
        self.data = data or {}
```

But I'm not quite sure, if this is correct workaround?!